# WCF Service hosted in internet

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a desktop app with WinForms.
Now I need to create an app that could collect data from my desktop app via internet. I mean that it is shuld be hosted somewhere in inetrnet
For example data is: is app online/ofline, and some information about computer where desktop client is launched.
And also I will need to develop a site where I can look throught this data.(think it will be ASP.NET)

I'm going to use WCF.
Is it good idea? 
Maybe there are some other technologes?

Comment: This kind of question is "too broad" here.

Comment: But do look at the newer stuff, maybe Application-Insights is all you need. Otherwise, consider WEB-API before WCF etc.

Comment: second of the web API

Comment: @HenkHolterman, why web api is better than wcf?

Comment: Have you looked at WCF yet?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, I'v read something.

Answer (score -1):

WCF is good idea. but if your application will use only http protocol then you should gave preference to web api.

Comment: In wich case I can work with out web api? If I will use TCP?

Comment: WCF supports Http,TCP, named pipe,P2p etc